# How does literals in compiled languages differ from literals in interpreted languages?

Tags: compilers, interpreters

A **literal** is a piece of data which gets its value at compile time.

Means: Becomes set at compile time and afterward the value is fixed incorporated into the machine code as a code consisting out of 0s and 1s.

**What are literals in interpreted languages like for example JavaScript?**

As far as I know the code within JavaScript functions aren't touched by the interpreter until it becomes executed.

**Can one say that literals exists in these languages?** regarding my definition of a literal (first paragraph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A literal is a piece of data which gets its value at compile time.

I don't think that's a good definition of literals. A literal is a source-code token that represents a fixed value of some type. For example, in almost all programming languages, `23` is a literal representing the integer twenty-three. These aren't pieces of data that get their value at compile-time: rather, they are representations of the values themselves.  For example if, in Java, you write

```
static final int magic = 23;
```

then `magic` is a constant (a variable whose value cannot be changed) that is set at compile-time to have the value twenty-three, which is the meaning of the literal `23`.

This is no different between compiled and interpreted languages.